# ASP.NET Web Forms: How can I pass a list to a user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, dry

My website has categories of posts (e.g. longreads, FAQs).
I am trying to display a list of links to category pages twice: in the header and in the footer.
So I have made a `CategoryList : UserControl` with a public `List<Category>`.

`CategoryList.ascx`:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CategoryList.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApp.Controls.CategoryList" %>

<% foreach (WebApp.Data.Category c in Categories) // .CategoriesList.Categories.get returned null
{ %>
<span>
    <a href="<%= GetRouteUrl("category-view", new { category = c.CategorySlug }) %>">
        <%= c.CategoryName %>
    </a> <!-- e.g. <a href="/category/longreads">Longreads</a> -->
</span>
<% } %>
```

`CategoryList.ascx.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WebApp.Controls
{
    public partial class CategoryList : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

        public List<Data.Category> Categories { get; set; }
    }
}
```

On the master page codebehind `MainMaster.Master.cs` I also have a `List<Category>` that is set during initialization like

```
public List<Category> Categories { get; } = Data.Categories.All.ToList();
```

Now in `MainMaster.Master` I try to display this control passing the list to it with an inline data-binding expression:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="custom" TagName="CategoryList" Src="~/Controls/CategoryList.ascx" %>
<!-- HTML form opening -->
    <custom:CategoryList Categories="<%# Categories %>" runat="server" />
<!-- HTML form closing -->
```

When I run this I get a `NullReferenceException` in `CategoryList.ascx` on the line

```
 foreach (WebApp.Data.Category c in Categories) // .CategoriesList.Categories.get returned null
```

Although when I try to do the same foreach loop on the page `MainMaster.Master` itself it works alright:

```
<!-- HTML form opening -->
<% foreach (WebApp.Data.Category c in Categories) // MainMaster.Categories
{ %>
    <span>
        <a href="<%= GetRouteUrl("category-view", new { category = c.CategorySlug }) %>">
            <%= c.CategoryName %>
        </a>
    </span>
<% } %>
<!-- HTML form closing -->
```

But I wouldn't like to repeat exactly the same code twice.
Is there a proper way I can pass a list to a user control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try assigning your categories in code behind, give the control an Id then reference it directly:

```
<custom:CategoryList runat="server" id="categoryList" />
```

You should be able to access it in your master page code behind:

```
categoryList.Categories = Data.Categories.All.ToList();
```

You will have to make sure depending on where you put this code, that your events fire in the correct order.